# Log4j disabling console logging

Tags: java, console, log4j

I need to make logger that will only log to file, but when I set XML likie this:

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="1MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
    <param name="file" value="${SERVER_HOME}/logs/mylog-log.txt" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.packageforlogging" additivity="true">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</logger>
```

It stills logs into console, because there are other loggers to which i don't have access. How I can do it?

Comment: Have you tried additivity=false on your logger?

Comment: Yes,  but it must be possible to add multiple loggers.

Comment: So you want to prevent other loggers logging to console, i.e. third-party JARs? You probably need to find what's logging and add logger entries with the logging switched off to suppress the output (or have them log only to file).